# TimePicker change time it self

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker, timepicker

this is code for kendo TimePicker, i have issue, **when you click out side date piker it will change time it self**. i have no idea how it is happen or no idea how to resolve it .

document url ::  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/timepicker/index

**[DEMO jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r262hzwj/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/timepicker/index">
    <style>
        html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        .hidden { display: none!important}
    </style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content">
            <h4>Set alarm time</h4>
            <input id="settimepicker" value="" title="timepicker" />
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // create TimePicker from input HTML element
                $("#settimepicker").kendoTimePicker({
                    dateInput: true,
                    dates: [
                        new Date(2000, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0),
                        new Date(2000, 9, 9, 9, 30, 0),
                        new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0),
                        new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 30, 0),
                        new Date(2000, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0),
                        new Date(2000, 11, 11, 11, 30, 0)
                    ] 
                });
            });
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#settimepicker").val(""); }, 500);

        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**any help or suggestion will be appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

```
 setTimeout(function(){ $("#settimepicker").val(""); }, 500);
```

put this **function inside**  `$(document).ready(function () {});`

it works then.